# How to create a very first user for django administraton page

Tags: django-admin

I want to be able to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ page using a user account and its corresponding password. The django webserver is up and running. I can see the Django administration page by accessing my localhost on port 8000. But the thing is that I don't have any user account and password set to access this.

Please look at the following output for confirmation:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> users
[]
>>>
```

My question is: how can I create a user and password accessing this adminstration page? I would like to work with my models defined in my application using this adminsitration page.

Thanks,
DjangoLer

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. If your code looks funny and not well formatted you can select it and click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you "manage.py syncdb" you will be prompted to complete the creation of an administration user.  If you have already done this and you weren't prompted, you may need to do a few things.

- First, make sure you didn't comment
  out any of the default middleware or
  installed apps.  See the Django
  documentation and tutorial for the
  default items that should be on
  there:
  [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/)
- If somehow you did and you already
  syncdb'd but weren't prompted, simply
  run "manage.py createsuperuser" and
  follow the prompts. More information
  about this can be found here:
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#createsuperuser